# Using .htaccess to route friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to route an url which is displayed as follows `www.example.com/profile/1` to the following page with parameters `www.example.com/profile?user=1`. I have the following `RewriteRule` in my .htaccess, yet the routing is not working. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/profile/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /profile?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried switching up the last `RewriteRule` to different URL's, but so far no luck. I am probably overseeing a small problem which someone can hopefully help me out with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow for `profile/\w+` as regex pattern to match `/profile/123`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngineOn
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)/?$ /profile?user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```